# Normalized laplacian matrix with eigen lib

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am little confused of definition of normalized laplacian matrix edfined as:

```
  D^{-1/2}*A*D^{-1/2}
```

The sentence of wiki: (isnt too much clear for me}::

the positive square roots of the corresponding positive diagonal entries of D

THe problem is if my D matrix have over 99 diagonal entries less then zero, so the square root of negative numbers can be done only with complex numbers...

does it mean that this sum have to be with abs() value? or input A matrix have to be rewrite with abs() values,....?

This is how I have it now:

```
 for ( int i=0; i < data.cols(); i++) {
    //Deg.sqrt();
    Deg(i,i)=1/(sqrt((data.cwiseAbs().row(i).sum())) );

  }

 Lapla=Deg*data*Deg;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normalized laplacian matrix is usually defined for networks, where A is the adjacency matrix and D is the diagonal matrix containing the degrees of the nodes. As an adjacency matrix, A has a one when the corresponding nodes are connected. Thus, as you say, the entries in D can be computing by taking row sums in A. But these sums are always positive, because you are adding zeros and ones. So I do not understand why your D matrix has negative numbers.

Maybe the edges in the network are weighted and some of the weights are negative? In that case, the definition of normalized laplacian matrix as `D^{-1/2}*A*D^{-1/2}` does not make sense, but I do not know what the correct definition is. I guess it depends on what you are using it for.